# How to change version numbers in themes from Official repository?

Tags: version-control

I'm developing my own theme, `anotherDuenaTheme`, based on the [Duena](https://wordpress.org/themes/duena/) theme.

How can I change version numbers of `anotherDuenaTheme` and use the information for auto-updates after an hypothetical update of `anotherDuenaTheme`? I want to use the theme in 10 websites and add new capabilities in each version.

Now I'm using [WP Updates](http://wp-updates.com)' system, which is enough for me (I know here are own-based ways to do it). With that easy system, after uploading a new version of `anotherDuenaTheme`, my WordPress installation advises me that there is a new version available.

The problem is that the copy of my theme has the same version of `OriginalDuenaTheme`, so after an update from 2.0.0 to 2.0.3 via the control panel, the `anotherDuenaTheme`'s advice for updating is still there... with no changes.

I've discovered that all the information from `OriginalDuenaTheme` is taken from WordPress core using `themes_api()` in file: `\wp-admin\includes\ajax-functions.php`

```
/** This filter is documented in wp-admin/includes/class-wp-theme-install-list-table.php */
$args = apply_filters( 'install_themes_table_api_args_' . $old_filter, $args );
$api = themes_api( 'query_themes', $args );
```

How can I disconnect my theme from using the Official Theme's directory?

I want to "succesfully" install another theme, different from the original, and have no wrong update notifications.

Comment: Can you please tell me whether you changed the "Theme Name", "Theme URI", and "Version" in style.css file of **anotherDuenaTheme** than what it is in original *Duena Theme*? Please refer the [guidelines here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Stylesheet) Once you confirm on this it will provide more inputs to debug further and assist.

Comment: Thanks! I was totally wrong about the place where themes store their information. After changing style.css, it works

Comment: Great.. so adding my comment as answer which will be helpful to other community users who come across similar problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change "Theme Name", "Theme URI", and "Version" in style.css file of **anotherDuenaTheme** so that it does not give update notifications belonging to original Duena Theme. Please refer the [guidelines here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Stylesheet)